Web callout 1 record at a time - Future vs Platform events
So I have a situation where the third party web callout can only process  record at a time.
From SF perspective, if I would like to mass process records and send them to the external web service.
I am thinking of. -

using future callout being called from a loop. So that each future will be its own transaction
create a platform event and make it process one record at a time. The trigger on platform event will process that single record

Is there any other option that may be better? Is future or platform event better compared to other? Considering governor limits and processing time

I would go platform event perhaps like this though you then have to kick off an async anyway. Is the problem the content of the callout or are there concurrency issues? Also what is the context of sending from SF? It may be you simply have a self-chaining Queueable to do the callouts.

Check out Dan Appleman's book Advanced Apex (latest edition), chapter "Going Async" for a pattern that works extremely well for this use case, including support for retries. In the absence of adopting that pattern, I'd use a chained queueable
